# Calling a Derived class ovverridden function in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, this, virtual

I have a class which is used as parent class and it has c () function which i want to override in derived class but the base class c function is getting called. Here is the pseudo code for my class.may be this keyword is giving it a different meaning whole together

```
public Class BaseRepository
{
    public A()
    {
        this.c();
    }

    public B()
    {
        this.c();
    }

    protected virtual c()
    {
        enter code here
    }
}
```

when i derive this class

```
class customRepo:BaseRepository
{
    protected override c()
    {
        ...does something
    }
}
```

My custom repo function is not using the `c()` from custom repo class but the base repo class 
function is being used.  Can anyone tell me why this is happening ???

Comment: This looks right provided that you are actually dealing with an instance of the customRepo class. Could your issue be that your overridden c function has a call to `base.c();`?

Comment: How are you calling it? Did you instantiate a custom Repo or a BaseRepository? If you instantiated the base class, it knows nothing about the derived class.

Comment: +1 McAden and Bradley.Net. Please show how you are calling c() and possibly relevant parts in the method.

Comment: If you can get away with it try making BaseRepository abstract, then you will get a compiler error if indeed you are creating an instance of the base class (as we all suspect your are)

Comment: I just made a sample on my machine, and it called the derived `c` function.  You should give us a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that actually demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely (and only I can come up with) reason this would be happening is that you instantiated a `BaseRepostiory` instead of a `customRepo` object.

Polymorphism invokes the most derived function **of the type that was actually created**, so creating a `customRepo` object will invoke customRepo.C, and creating a `BaseRepository` will invoke BaseRepository.C.

To expound further, classes do not magically know about their derivations, nor do they call derived methods. This makes sense, because if you had multiple derivations, which method would you call? The following line will work as you expect (calling the derived class):

```
BaseRepository custom = new customRepo();
custom.A();
```

This one will not:

```
BaseRepository base = new BaseRepostiory();
base.A();
```

Comment: I was trying to instantiate wrong class with wing name